# Gii not detecting mysql tables in model creator

Tags: yii, gii

From config/main.php :

```
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

When I use the gii model generator (http://localhost/yii/testdelete/index.php?r=gii/model) and try to put "post" or "user" in the table name and click "Preview" it says:

Table 'post' does not exist.

I want to be able to create models using those tables.

Exporting from phpMyAdmin:

```
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Database: `testdb`
```

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_on` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type "s" into Table Name field auto complete should pop up with both tables.

check that

1. you have saved the config file (close it and open again to verify its content)
2. you have one db section in your config file (maybe you have sqlite one overwriting it)
3. check that you are on same mysql instance. phpMyAdmin host 127.0.0.1 doesnt meant its the same instance, its the instance phpMyAdmin runs on (check the url). Login from command line (or use wonderful desktop client http://www.heidisql.com/) to poke around in localhost database

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip about autocomplete. Anyway the only table that would come up was tbl_user. I modified config/console.php and commented out "'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db'," and added the mysql info and now gii works properly using the mysql tables 'post' and 'user'.

Comment: If I put config/console.php back it just uses the database info from config/main.php again...